# GCP Deployment Manager - What Dev Ops Tool To Use In Conjunction?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, devops, google-deployment-manager

I'm presently looking into GCP's Deployment Manager to deploy new projects, VMs and Cloud Storage buckets.
We need a web front end that authenticated users can connect to in order to deploy the required infrastructure, though I'm not sure what Dev Ops tools are recommended to work with this system. We have an instance of Jenkins and Octopus Deploy, though I see on Google's Configuration Management page (https://cloud.google.com/solutions/configuration-management) they suggest other tools like Ansible, Chef, Puppet and Saltstack.

I'm supposing that through one of these I can update something simple like a name variable in the config.yaml file and deploy a project.

Could I also ensure a chosen name for a project, VM or Cloud Storage bucket fits with a specific naming convention with one of these systems?

Which system do others use and why?

Comment: Hi, can you provide your detailed use case in this context “web front end that authenticated users”?

As per the [doc](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/infrastructure-as-code) GCP support terraform, puppet, ansible … as IaC solution along with Deployment manager.

Also you can find supported [CI tools](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/continuous-integration) and [CD tools](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/continuous-delivery) in these docs.

Comment: deployment manager is designed to provision GCP resources, the page you linked mentions configuration tools to use with it. IE DM would provision the infrastructure and then something like Ansible will configure your front end with appropriate application and settings

Comment: In essence, DM just replaced terraform in your DevOps toolbox

Answer (score 1):

I use Deployment Manager, as all 3rd party tools are reliant upon the presence of GCP APIs, as well as trusting that those APIs are in line with the actual functionality of the underlying GCP tech.

GCP is decidedly behind the curve on API development, which means that even if you *wanted* to use TF or whatever, at some point you're going to be stuck inside the SDK, anyway. So that's why I went with Deployment Manager, as much as I wanted to have my whole infra/app deployment use other tools that I was more comfortable with.

To specifically answer your question about validating naming schema, what you would probably want to do is write a wrapper script that uses the `gcloud deployment-manager` subcommand. Do your validation in the wrapper script, *then* run the `gcloud deployment-manager` stuff.

Word of warning about Deployment Manager: it makes troubleshooting very difficult. Very often it will obscure the error that can help you actually establish the root cause of a problem. I can't tell you how many times somebody in my office has shouted "UGGH! Shut UP with your `Error 400!`" I hope that Google takes note from my pointed survey feedback and refactors DM to pass the original error through.

Anyway, hope this helps. GCP has come a long way, but they've still got work to do.

Comment: Thanks very much! I think I'll look into possibly hosting the Deployment Manager scripts within App Engine (within the project that has the service account to create projects). Then we can simply browse to a URL, add in the appropriate configuration like name, etc. and click on a nice big button called "Deploy".

Comment: Hey, @TitianRob16, just a heads up, I'm now 2 for 2 with me asking a GCP subject matter expert - both Google employees and 3rd party support partners - for help with Deployment Manager, and literally their first response being, "WHY did you go with Deployment Manager and not something else that's more mature, like Terraform?" So, that said, I now have a couple of tickets in my backlog for refactoring our whole thing in TF. Maybe look into that before getting stuck in the Deployment Manager K-Hole too deeply.

Comment: Thanks, @ingernet! I have learnt that recently as Google Deployment Manager is constantly throwing red herring 403 error messages, even with the simple gcloud command. Since moving to Terraform, we haven't had any issues whatsoever.